# Why must HttpModule be imported in my AppModule?

Tags: angular

I have a simple Angular2 app with two modules: AppModule and TableTopModule.

ShipService, which relies on HttpModule, is imported in the TableTopModule and **only** used by a public component in that module.

```
Error: No provider for Http!
```

Importing HttpModule in the AppModule instead fixes this error, and Http becomes available in my ShipService.

Why does it work in my AppModule, but not the TableTopModule? Is AppModule special in some way because it's used to bootstrap the app?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I had forgotten to import the TableTopModule itself into the AppModule. After doing that, importing the HttpModule in TableTopModule worked as expected.